# symbol table for debug in windows

Tags: c++, debugging, compilation, symbols

I want to compile and use Visual studio for checking an unmanaged C++ on windows program.
I am using ADPlus and WinDBG. For doing this I need a .pdb file amd to configure the symbols of my debugging.

How u can configure it (to local machine and not the net) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` in the environment to include the location of your PDB file(s).  See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) for detailed info, esp. if you want to get symbol info for the NT libs in your debug sessions.

You can also modify the symbol path dynamically in the Windbg GUI from the `File` menu, but this does not persist after you close WinDbg.

Comment: What do you do if you have a computer that is not connected to the net (work policy) ? how then you can download the right pdb for the windows os ?

Comment: @Roman - you should be able to get a copy of the symbols that matches your OS and copy them locally to the computer's HDD.  this is a lot harder though, since there are always SPs and hotfixes to take into account.

Comment: Do you have a link that explains the process it self why u need debug symbol and debugging tools ?

Comment: @Roman - check this out: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx